# Count identical row values for each pair of columns to create network graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have data like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  music = c("classical", "jazz", "baroque", "electronic", "ambient"),
  john = c(1,1,0,1,1),
  jeff = c(1,0,0,1,0),
  jane = c(0,1,1,0,0)
)

       music john jeff jane
1  classical    1    1    0
2       jazz    1    0    1
3    baroque    0    0    1
4 electronic    1    1    0
5    ambient    1    0    0
```

And want to graph the overlap between the individuals on the columns - how often do they both have 1s in the same row?  If I could get to this `data.frame`:

```
result <- data.frame(person1 = c("john", "john", "jeff"), person2 = c("jeff", "jane", "jane"), overlap = c(2, 1, 0))

  person1 person2 overlap
1    john    jeff       2
2    john    jane       1
3    jeff    jane       0
```

I could create the graph I have in mind:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(result, directed = FALSE)
plot(g, edge.width = result$overlap * 3)
```

But I'm struggling to transform the data to count row-wise overlap between each pair of columns.  How can I do that?

Comment: Try using `m <- crossprod(as.matrix(dat[-1])` and then `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` (given your outcome, you probably need to set the diagonals to zero diag(m) <- 0`)

Comment: @user20650 That is a perfect answer; I think you should make it official.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably an easier approach is to create the adjacency matrix of the graph by taking the crossproduct. You can then read this in directly to igraph.

```
library(igraph)

# Take the crossproduct: assumes unique music types in each row
# otherwise aggregate terms
m <- crossprod(as.matrix(dat[-1]))

# You could remove the diagonal terms here
# although it is useful to see the sum for each individual
# You can also remove it in igraph, as below
# diag(m) <- 0

# Create graph
# The weights are stored in E(g)$weight
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, mode="undirected", weighted = TRUE)

# Remove edge loops
g <- simplify(g)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to experiment with different similarity/distance measures, like Russel/Roa, Jaccard etc. I mean: 0 and 0 can be interpreted as similarity, too. Anyway, here's another approach:

```
library(proxy)
m <- (1-as.matrix(dist( t(dat[, -1]), method = "Russel")))*nrow(dat)
m[lower.tri(m, T)] <- NA
(res <- setNames(reshape2::melt(m, na.rm=T), c("p1", "p2", "ol")))
#     p1   p2 ol
# 4 john jeff  2
# 7 john jane  1
# 8 jeff jane  0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for your example:

```
# build name matrix
nameMat <- t(combn(names(dat[,-1]), 2))
# pre-allocate count vector
overLap <- integer(nrow(nameMat))

# loop through name combos
for(i in 1:nrow(nameMat)) {
  overLap[i] <- sum(rowSums(dat[, nameMat[i,]]) == 2)
}
# construct data.frame
df <- data.frame("person1"=nameMat[,1], "person2"=nameMat[,2], "overLap"=overLap)
```

If you don't like `for` loops, you can use `sapply` to get the overlap count:

```
overLap <- sapply(1:(nrow(nameMat)), 
                  function(i) sum(rowSums(dat[, nameMat[i,]]) == 2))
```

As suggested by @user20650, you can also calculate the overlap using `combn`:

```
overLap <- combn(dat[-1], 2, FUN=function(i) sum(rowSums(i)==2))
```

A long method of calculating overlap is as follows:
    overLap <- sapply(1:(nrow(nameMat)), function(i) sum(rowSums(dat[, nameMat[i,]] == c(1,1)) == 2))

This longer version has one advantage in that it can be generalized to the situation where these measures are on a likert scale (indicating intensity of affinity). In the situation of a 5 point scale, c(1,1) could be changed to c(3,3) to examine indifference or c(5,5). If the interest were in polar opposite opinions, such as c(1,5), the nameMat would have to be manipulated and copied:

```
newNameMat <- rbind(nameMat, cibind(nameMat[,2], nameMat[,1])
```

and calculations performed on this matrix. It wouldn't be too hard to wrap these operations into a function that could count any pairwise comparison of likert scale combinations.

Comment: for your last calculation you can do this in combn.. `combn(dat[-1], 2, FUN=function(x) sum(rowSums(x)==2))`, but you can maybe do it all together...`t(combn(dat[-1], 2,  FUN=function(x) c(names(x), sum(rowSums(x)==2))))` (although im sure this can be simplified)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @user20650. I haven't used `combn` in this manner before. I added your first `comb` suggestion to my answer.